# use jquery to create buttons that turn sub-groups of data on and off - from arrays of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create buttons that will turn on and off sub-groups of data.
I structured my data as an array of arrays. I then created an array of group names that I want to create buttons for.
I want to assign each subgroup to a button, and when the button is clicked, all data from the subgroup will be displayed.
Here is a diagram showing which data is assigned to which button in case that helps:
[image: diagram of how things are related]

My code so far is below. I have managed to get the last item in each sub-group (the arrays within the larger array) to show up when clicking on the button.
However I want all of the subgroup data to show up, and then get hidden when I click the button again. I have been stuck on this for a while. Thank you for any help.

Here is a jsfiddle, too:
https://jsfiddle.net/vtctcbjp/

```js
$("#biggroup").click(function() {
  $("#menu").html("");

  // array (big group) of arrays (sub-groups)
  groupToggleableLayerIds.push(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h']);

  // button names for sub-groups
  layerName = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];

  // call the function
  layerButtons(groupToggleableLayerIds);
});

var groupToggleableLayerIds = [];
var layerName = [];

function layerButtons(groupToggleableLayerIds) {

  for (var i = 0; i < groupToggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
    var grouping = groupToggleableLayerIds[i];
    console.log("grouping", grouping);
    var groupName = layerName[i];
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = 'active';
    link.textContent = groupName;

    grouping.forEach(function(element) {

      for (var i = 0; i < grouping.length; i++) {
        var id = grouping[i];
        console.log("id", id);
        link.class = id;
      } // end for (grouping.length)

      link.onclick = function(element) {
        for (var i = 0; i < grouping.length; i++) {

          var visibility = $('#' + id).css('visibility');
          console.log("visibility", visibility);

          if (visibility === 'visible') {
            $('#' + id).css('visibility', 'none');
            this.className = '';
          } else {
            this.className = 'active';
            $('#' + id).css('visibility', 'visible');
          }
        } // end for (grouping.length)
      }; // end link.onclick

    }) // end grouping.forEach

    var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
    layers.appendChild(link);
  }; // end for (groupToggleableLayerIds.length)

}; // end layerButtons function
```

```css
#biggroup {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#menu a {
  padding: 20px;
}

#layers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}

#layers div {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="biggroup">BIG GROUP</button>
<nav id="menu"></nav>
<div id="layers">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
  <div id="d">D</div>
  <div id="e">E</div>
  <div id="f">F</div>
  <div id="g">G</div>
  <div id="h">H</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I clicked `<>` snippet editor for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i modified 2 thing(s) in your answer:
 1st `$('#' + id).css('visibility', 'none');` to `$('#' + id).css('visibility', 'hidden');`.
2nd I added an index to the link element and made a loop of layer to get the buttons bellow is the implementation of the javascript:

```js
function layerButtons(groupToggleableLayerIds, layerName) 
{
  for (var i = 0; i < layerName.length; i++)
  {
    var groupName = layerName[i];
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = 'active';
    link.textContent = groupName;
    link.dataset.index = i;

    link.onclick = function(element) {
      groupToggleableLayerIds[element.target.dataset.index].forEach(function(id) {
        var visibility = $('#' + id).css('visibility');
        console.log("visibility", visibility);

        if (visibility === 'visible') {
          $('#' + id).css('visibility', 'hidden');
          this.className = '';
        } else {
          this.className = 'active';
          $('#' + id).css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
      });
    };
    var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
    layers.appendChild(link);
  }
}
```

and here is the edited demo link:https://jsfiddle.net/vikscool/n0L496zp/

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate you showing how you made edits to my code to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the id of links with array index and then later on use that to get sub array indexes. I have updated your fiddle and its working.

```
var groupToggleableLayerIds = [];
var layerName = [];

$("#biggroup").click( function(){
  $("#menu").html("");

  groupToggleableLayerIds.push(['a','b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h']);

  layerName = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];

  layerButtons(groupToggleableLayerIds);
});

//when any of the link is clicked
$("#menu").on('click', '.link', function() {
    var toShow;
    var id = $(this).prop("id"); //get id of clicked link

    //compare id and get sub array
    if(id == "link0") {  
      toShow = groupToggleableLayerIds[0];
    }
    else if(id == "link1") {
      toShow = groupToggleableLayerIds[1];
    }
    else if(id == "link2") {
      toShow = groupToggleableLayerIds[2];
    }
    else if(id == "link3") {
      toShow = groupToggleableLayerIds[3];
    }

    //loop over layers
    $("#layers div").each(function(i, v){
      var layerId = $(this).prop("id");

      //check if sub array contains id of layer then make it visible
      if(toShow.indexOf(layerId) > -1) {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
    else {
      //otherwise hide it
      $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
  });
});

//only adding the buttons to HTML
function layerButtons(groupToggleableLayerIds){  
  for (var i = 0; i < groupToggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
      var link = document.createElement('a');

      link.href = '#';
      link.className = 'active link'; //we will use this class to bind event handler
      link.textContent = layerName[i];
      link.id = "link" + i; //this set index of array as id

      document.getElementById('menu').appendChild(link);
  };
};
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vtctcbjp/1/)**

**OR**

if you want to hide a `layer` only when its `link` is clicked, toggle the previous state of `layer` like this:

```
$("#layers div").each(function(i, v){
    var layerId = $(this).prop("id");
    var state;

    if(toShow.indexOf(layerId) > -1) {

      state = $(this).css('visibility');

      if(state == 'hidden') {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
      }
        else {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
      }
    }
  });
```

**[DEMO2](https://jsfiddle.net/vtctcbjp/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but I could only choose one answer. I upvoted, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier using jQuery. Here is a solution using the text of the link to determine which layers to show:

(JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Hulothe/k6xyk2Lm/)

```js
$("#biggroup").click(function() {
    $("#menu").html("");

    // array (big group) of arrays (sub-groups)
    groupToggleableLayerIds.push(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h']);

    // button names for sub-groups
    layerName = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];

    // call the function
    layerButtons(groupToggleableLayerIds);
});

var groupToggleableLayerIds = [];
var layerName = [];

function layerButtons(groupToggleableLayerIds) {

    for (var i = 0; i < groupToggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
        var groupName = layerName[i];
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#';
        link.className = 'link';
        link.textContent = groupName;

        $('#menu').append(link);
    }; // end for (groupToggleableLayerIds.length)

}; // end layerButtons function

$('#menu').on('click', '.link', function() {
    var text = $(this).text(),
        pos = layerName.indexOf(text);
    if (pos > -1) {
        for (i = 0; i < groupToggleableLayerIds[pos].length; i++) {
            console.log('elem', $('#layers > div#' + groupToggleableLayerIds[pos][i]));
            toggleVisibility($('#layers > div#' + groupToggleableLayerIds[pos][i]));
        }
    }
});

function toggleVisibility(elem) {
    if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

```css
#biggroup {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#menu a {
    padding: 20px;
}

#layers {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
}

#layers div {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="biggroup">BIG GROUP</button>
<nav id="menu"></nav>
<div id="layers">
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
    <div id="d">D</div>
    <div id="e">E</div>
    <div id="f">F</div>
    <div id="g">G</div>
    <div id="h">H</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but I could only choose one answer. I upvoted, though.